# Set folder title using SharePoint PnP in Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to set the Title property of SharePoint folders under "My documents" library. I can use SharePoint PnP to create the folder, for example:

```
$folder = Resolve-PnPFolder -SiteRelativePath "My documents/folderA"
```

But I couldn't find a way to set the Title property of the folder using SharePoint PnP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default folders from sharepoint i don't think you can use the title property. You would need to create a new content type based on the default folder content type and then set the title property to optional or required. Just keep in mind that whenever you change the name property of the folder it will override the value of the title property.

If you mean rename the folder you can use this line of code to change the name property.

```
Rename-PnPFolder -Folder "My Documents/folderA" -TargetFolderName "folderB"
```

Comment: I found out that I can change the Title through SharePoint online portal and it is independent of Name property. But I need to do it programmatically and I can't find how to do using SharePoint PnP.

Comment: @user3616544, you can check the script in my answer, it should be able to set folder title, if it's working, I suggest you could accept as answer so that it could help others in the forum :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the script as below to set a folder Title property:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$ListName="Documents"
$FolderServerRelativeURL = "/sites/sitename/Shared Documents/Folder1"
$UserAccount = "jerry@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
  
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Get the Folder from URL
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $FolderServerRelativeURL
     
#Set Permission to Folder
Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $Folder.ListItemAllFields -Values @{"Title" = "Test Title"}
```

[image]